# How to synchronize background with terminal using solarized colorscheme with neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal, colorscheme, background

When I toggle my terminal from a dark to light colorscheme, neovim doesn't match:

- If my terminal is dark and I open `nvim`, nvim is dark (`:set bg` says `dark`)
- If my terminal is light and I open `nvim`, nvim is still dark (but `:set bg` says `light`)
- If I toggle my terminal from dark to light *while* `nvim` is open, nvim correctly toggles from dark to light as well (but `bg` incorrectly reports `dark`)
- If I supend vim while it is light (ctrl+z), when I resume, vim reverts back to dark (and `bg` reports `light`)

I'm pretty sure this problem started just today, and nvim used to synchronize perfectly with my terminal before this. What can I do to ensure nvim is always in sync with my terminal's light/dark colorscheme?

- Terminal: [st](https://st.suckless.org/) with the [solarized-both](https://st.suckless.org/patches/solarized/st-solarized-both-0.8.4.diff) patch.
- Neovim: 0.8.0
- Colorscheme: [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized).
- TERM: `xterm-256color`

I'm running `nvim -u init.vim` where `init.vim` contains only `colorscheme solarized`

Answer (score 0):

`set bg=dark` in `init.vim` solved it for me. I verified that the value is "dark" even before I run `set bg=dark`, but somehow running that explicitly seems to fix the issue.